# GStreamer reading from stream is good enough performance, but write back to the stream is an overkill process, Why?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-streaming, gstreamer

I want to improve the writing stream performance of `GStreamer` pipeline.

When I read from `RTSP` stream, the CPU usage is about 1%~2% which is very nice, but when I write the frame back to the RTMP/UDP stream over network, is an overkill task, which the CPU usage goes up to 17%, it is the case which I did not perform any image process (just read and directly write back), so if I start to process 2+ channels of IP camera images simultaneously, then the CPU usage is going to be full almost.

**So** the question is, how can I keep the writing quality as read (1~2% of CPU usage)? Below is how I call the read/write process:

**Read:**

```
String url = "rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/102" +
        " latency=0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink";
if (!capture.open(url, Videoio.CAP_GSTREAMER)) {
    System.out.println("error opening capture");
    return;
}
```

**Write:**

```
String urlWriter = "appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency threads=2 ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=localhost port=5000";
writer.open(urlWriter, Videoio.CAP_GSTREAMER, fourcc, 15, new Size(width, height), true);
if (!writer.isOpened()) {
    System.out.println("error open writer");
    return;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: @zindarod Thanks for the reply! But I am wondering why the writing task is heavy then the reading. And also can you tell me which encoder is better for speed, I have tried some other encoders but the result was not working. like `jpegenc`

Comment: You need to understand that video encoding is very CPU heavy. Try adding the option `speed-preset=ultrafast` to your `x264enc` for some speed ups. It will however always be much more expensive than decoding.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Thanks, bro! It really speeded up the process time (2~3%). I asked this question because, when I use ffmpeg on the command line `ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:1234@xxxxx:554/Streaming/Channels/102 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://xxxxx:5000/mylive) which does the same thing (read -> write` but the CPU is always 0%, I was wondering how it is possible with ffmpeg but not with GStreamer, but I am still wondering although the speed is now more fast.

Comment: It is certainly possible. You should not transcode your video. In your gstreamer case you decode and encode your video. In the ffmpeg case you just reformat the data. Instead of `decodebin`  you may want try `parsebin`. Or tell `decodebin` to stop putting in elements at a certain stage via the `caps` option and feed it to the `mpegtsmux`.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch One question I wanna ask you, that is when I run the above FFmpeg command, then in the VLC and HTML video tag both I can open the video stream, but when I try the same routine with GStreamer, then the stream can only be opened in VLC, in the HTML video cannot be opened. It is why? Note: in the middle, there is NGINX media server which receives the stream (from FFmpeg or GStreamer) and then from VLC or HTML video tag read the stream.

Comment: I have no idea.. sometimes you use RTMP, sometimes you use MPEGTS. One case is with audio, the other not.. you expectations are hard to compare in these cases..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch when I use RTMP, then I can only use flvmux not MPEGTS, because I have tried if I not used flvmux, RTMP not working `appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency threads=2 byte-stream=true ! flvmux streamable=true ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://xxxxx:5000/mylive` But the problem is it is not working in the HTML page, but working in VLC player. But if I change to FFmpeg, both working well. Both ffmpeg and GStreamer write the stream into RTMP media server which is NGINX. Then VLC and HTML read the stream form NGINX server. Which FFmpeg is OK, but GST not

Comment: So I am wondering why the stream can be opened from HTML and VLC while FFMPEG is writing the stream to the NGINX server, but when the stream is written by GStreamer, only VLC is working HTML is not working.

Comment: So on HTML you use the Flash player, right? It may be that it requires an audio track. Perhaps this does the trick: `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:1234@xxxxx:554/Streaming/Channels/102 ! parsebin : flvmux ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://xxxxx:5000/mylive`. Only works with Gstreamer 1.12 and up. If the camera does not provide an audio track you may have to generate one on your own with audiotestsrc for example.

Comment: Thanks, bro! It seems that you got the point. Yes, I am using flash player, as you mentioned, yes, the camera provides audio track because it works well with FFMEPG, so now the point is: I am reading the stream, and then process the image, and then write it back to the RTMP stream, so here, it may be missed the audio track, so I will try to generate one my self. By the way, I have tried the `parsebin` but not working, can you please give me how to use `parsebin` if it is possible. Thanks very much!

Comment: `parsebin` is working well on the command line (CPU %0 or 0.1%), but how to implement it in the code (read -> process -> write)

Comment: If you want to really process both media you need to grab from the parsebin/decodebin twice. So you will end up with two appsink and two appsrc. I suggest reading https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/#pipeline-description

Comment: But here in OpenCV how can retrieve the audio from the capture? OpenCV does not have any API to retrieve audio. So I am really confusing with this. :((